# A bloated riddle

Tags: riddle

You can find me in the air, on the water, on rails and on the road.
The general has led me into existence, and he also caused my demise.
I have created games, supported xenophobes and studied things both earthly and unearthly.
I have informed people in multiple ways, but also ended lives.

Who or what am I?

Hint #1

> I have not always been around.

Hint #2

> I am a tangible and defined object.

Hint #3

> The games in the 3rd line refer to video games.

Hint #4

> You mainly know me from my air implementation.

Hint #5

> All the items on which the riddle is based can be found on my Wikipedia disambiguation page.

Hint #6

> The xenophobes referred to in the riddle often make allusions to race purity. Their leader was seen as one of the biggest dictators of the 20th century.

Hint #7 (the last one)

> The first letter of my name is also the last letter.

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, Hint #7 is incorrect, right?

Comment: 'Z' isn't the last letter of the word Zeppelin, but it is the last letter of something else...

Comment: what about hint 7?

Comment: @roel What's the last letter of the English alphabet?

Comment: letter T  :)    I got it. What was I thinking. Thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> Zeppelin

Here's why:

You can find me in the air,

> The famous airship

on the water,

> The ship SS Zeppelin

on rails

> Rail Zeppelin

and on the road.

> Maybach Zeppelin

The general has led me into existence,

> Ferdinand von Zeppelin

and he also caused my demise.

I have created games,

> Zeppelin Games

supported xenophobes

> Zeppelin Field

and studied things both earthly and unearthly.

> Zeppelin research station

I have informed people in multiple ways,

> Zeppelin mail

but also ended lives.

Comment: Yes, it is zeppelin. Let's see if you also get all of the references.

Comment: (don't forget the led zepelin part :3 )

Comment: Working on it. Shout out to @RNar for some of the groundwork

Comment: I was so close! I mentioned Zeppelin in my answer too, aaahh I should have seen it

Comment: Good one. Does hint #7 apply though?

Comment: @ruudvan yes it does. Note how I don't specify of what exactly the last letter is.

Comment: @Nzall, touche.

Comment: You found almost all the references. you're missing bloated, led, demise, unearthly, ended lives and the hints.

Comment: What about (General) Hindenburg for the demise? WW1 Zeppelin bombing raids ending lives?

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is:

> Balloons

You can find me in the air:

> Hot air balloons

on the water

> Not sure YET

on rails

> Possibly refer to either Balloon loop or English Electric Balloon tram

on the road.

> English Electric balloon tram

The general has led me into existence, and he also caused my demise.

> I am guessing an allusion to airships like the Zeppelin or maybe a specific allusion to the Hindenburg.

I have created games,

> Bloons!

supported xenophobes,

> balloons are used as a form of transportation

and studied things both earthly and unearthly

> weather balloons and space balloons

I have informed people in multiple ways, but also ended lives.

> ! Not too sure about this one but can allude to a combination of aforementioned things.
>   TO BE FINISHED.

Comment: You're close. I'm looking for a mode of air transportation, but not airplanes.

Comment: Does the title give a large hint to this object? Because if so, and after looking at the disambiguation of the object I have in mind, I think i have the answer.

Comment: Yes, the title also refers to the object.

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: You're nearly there. I'm looking for a specific kind of balloon, with a disambiguation page on Wikipedia that has an item for each of the aspects of the riddle.

Comment: Check my final hint.

Comment: You should go for a zepelin, it fits most of the lines... especially the information/killing parts, and there is a pun with led zepelin :)

Comment: it's Zeppelin isnt it

Comment: Not posting a new answer cause I like my xenon one, but it definitely fits, with the last hint too (hitler)

Comment: damn. and somebody else posted the answer too haha

Comment: Hope I didn't steal your thunder :)

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> xenon?

You can find me in the air, on the water on rails and on the road

> xenon is a gas present in the atmosphere

The general has led me into existence, and he also caused my demise

> General Xenon was an officer in the old greece

I have created games, supported xenophobes and studied things both earthly and unearthly

> Xenon is a video game, and xenon gas was used in creating toxic gas during wars. There is xenon on earth and in meteorits.

I have informed people in multiple ways, but also ended lives.

> as stated before it has been used in toxic gas, and it has also been used to create photographs in the XX century.

Comment: it is not xenon, no. It's something that once didn't exist, but was made to exist.

Answer (score 1):

(removed my old answer)  IT'S

> Technology

You can find me in the air, on the water, on rails and on the road.

> Places you can see technology (often carting us about).

The general has led me into existence, and he also caused my demise.

> technology is often developed first by military powers and they like to smash it up sometimes too

I have created games, supported xenophobes and studied things both earthly and unearthly.

> videogames, media, telescopes etc,

I have informed people in multiple ways, but also ended lives.

> the internet, nukes etc.

Comment: It's neither Internet nor Technology. It's tangible and defined.

Comment: Awww.  Was so sure.  tangible you say?  Hmmm.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think you are

> war

Comment: Nope, not war. War is not tangible.

Answer (score 1):

> Asbestos?
>  Tangeable,
>
> found almost everywhere anything man made is,
>
> the government installed it in homes and public buildings all over and then got rid of it,
>
> used in all manner of study,
>
> lots of scientific discoveries may not have been made if not for asbestos and it has definitely ended a lot of lives

Comment: Nope, not Asbestos. Asbestos hasn't created the kind of games I'm talking about, at least not in the way I intended.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's

> Processor

You can find me in the air, on the water, on rails and on the road.

> planes, boats, trains and cars all use processors

The general has led me into existence, and he also caused my demise.

> I think this refers to electricity, power on/off, or humans creating and destroying hardware

I have created games, supported xenophobes and studied things both earthly and unearthly.

> video games, researches (earth and space) done with processor power

I have informed people in multiple ways

> phones, internet...

but also ended lives.

> bombs, drones...

I have not always been around.

> Created by humans

I am a tangible and defined object.

> checked

Comment: Nope, not processor. with "caused my demise", I mean that a general has caused the object to effectively stop being used except for novelty purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer

> Falcon

You can find me in the air,

> The bird, and also a few militaristic implements

on the water,

> Names of ships in Royal Navy and US Navy ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_(disambiguation)))

on rails

> Old locomotives (wiki too)

and on the road.

> A Ford model and other things

The general has led me into existence, and he also caused my demise.

> Don't know yet

I have created games,

> A series of combat flight simulator computer games

supported xenophobes

> Don't know yet

and studied things both earthly and unearthly.

> Don't know yet

I have informed people in multiple ways,

> Don't know yet

but also ended lives.

> Don't know yet

Comment: Nope, not a falcon, although the elements that you've found were interpreted correctly. I'm looking for a different disambiguation page that does have connections to all those things.